# Find integration with limit from 1 to 2

Tags: integration

Find the integration [image]

my try :

[image]

Unable to solve further

Comment: It may help to note that $$\int_0^1\frac{te^{2t}}{e(1-t)+te^{2t}}dt=\int_0^1\frac{te^{2t}+e(1-t)}{e(1-t)+te^{2t}}dt+e\int_0^1\frac{t-1}{e(1-t)+te^{2t}}dt\\=1+e\int_0^1\frac{t-1}{e(1-t)+te^{2t}}dt$$

Answer (score 2):

Being almost blind, I have problems trying to read your notes.

What it seems to me is that there is a symmetry around $x=\frac 32$. So, let $x=y+\frac 32$ to make the integrand to be
$$f(y)=\frac{e^{2 y} (2 y+1)}{1-2 y+e^{2 y} (2 y+1)}$$ which makes
$$f(y)+f(-y)=1$$
So, you do not need integration at all. The result is the area of a right triangle the vertices of coordinates being $(-\frac 12,0)$, $(\frac 12,0)$, $(\frac 12,1)$.

Now, a simple result.

Now, just behind you and me, there is no antiderivative to the function. I suppose that this problem is just a trap !